# Web Service for getting song information from an MD5 hash or similar?

Tags: php, web-services

Do any web services exist for getting song information (artist, song title, etc) when you provide a hash of the song file?

If no, what other ways are there of getting such information, and do you know of any decent PHP libraries for such?

Thanks.

Comment: An MD5 hash is probably not the best way to do it; if the audio is reencoded, it may change. If someone adds or removes a little silence at the beginning or end, it will change.

Comment: I don't think there are any services that go by a hash of a file. Hashes are explicitly designed to be _unique_ so they "amplify" even the tiniest differences between two files. If a single bit is different the hash will be completely different. To recognize songs, you need something that instead minimizes differences, like fourier transforms or something.

Comment: Yeah, I know, however if downloading from a service like iTunes, etc, they'll be the same. Pirated music is more likely to be a bit off, I'd imagine, and I'm not going to go out of my way to help them.

Comment: But, knowing that, are there any services for music identification that you know of?

Comment: @Muu: I think even iTunes downloads will be different. I think they add you userID to the file somewhere (at least they did that once, so the record companies could track files that ended up on filesharing services), so that'll throw of the hashing for each file

Comment: Fair point, though perhaps I could strip stuff like that out.

Comment: I think they'd design it to be hard to strip out, because otherwise pirates *would* strip them out before distributing them.

Comment: Oh right, of course - I assumed it'd be stored as metadata but that'd be pointless. (Though I'd imagine many would leave it in, not knowing it was there).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is called [acoustic fingerprinting](http://wiki.musicbrainz.org/AudioFingerprint).